# Why a big number input will generate a runtime error for this code to compute primeCounting?

Tags: c++, c++11, count, runtime-error, primes

The task is to count the number of primes numbers below an input parameter N.
I am testing this code with different input number ranging from small to large. It is very strange, I only encountered a runtime error if the input value is larger and equal than 46342. If the input value is smaller than 46342, the code runs perfectly fine without any runtime error.

```
int countPrimes(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) return 0;
    vector<bool> array(n,true);
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 2 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i ; i * j < n ; j++)
        {

            int product = i * j;
            if (array[product])
            {
                array[product] = false;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return n - 2 - cnt;
}
```

If the input is bigger and equal than 46342, I will see "Runtime Error
", if the input is smaller than 46342, the code runs fine and the result is correct.

Comment: You could have simply printed out the value of `product` to see your error.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
int product = i * j;
```

will overflow, making `product` equal to a negative number.

Then, you will attempt to access `array` (which is actually a vector, so naming it `array` is not a good choice) with a negative index, which will make your program crash.

---

You need to use types that can support larger numerical values. Now you used `int` ([C++ Integer Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2017)). Use `unsigned int` for `n`, `i`, `j`, and `product`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought in my loop condition for (int j = i ; i * j < n ; j++), since i * j < n, it will guarantee that we don't overflow for product = i * j, am I right?

Comment: `i * j` overflows @newbie, so the expression that you try to evaluate to guard it is also bugged. You have to use a bigger data type, such as `unsigned int`, or `long int`.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much, that really solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome @newbie. Welcome to Stack Overflow, You posted a good first question, that's why I upvoted you. Don't forget to accept an answer, from the ones posted here.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of an `int` is the 31th power of 2, which is equal to 2147483648.
The square root of this is 46340.95, so the value you're working with (by performing `i*j`) goes above that limit, causing the runtime exception.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, those answer above does solve my problem. I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers, what the OP is experiencing is the combination of two issues, integer overflow and out of bounds access of a vector, both causes of undefined behavior.

The line

```
int product = i * j;
```

Declares an `int` variable initialized with the product of `i` and `j` which are of type `int`, which, quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

> If no length modifiers are present, it's guaranteed to have a width of at least 16 bits. However, on 32/64 bit systems it is almost exclusively guaranteed to have width of at least 32 bits.

Apparently, in OP's system an `int` has a 32-bit width, so that a value of `i` greater then 46341 makes the operation 46342 * 46342 = 2147580964 overflow the range of representable numbers (INT_MAX likely beeing 2147483647).

In case of overflow, the behavior is undefined, but in most architectures, where integers are represented in 2's complement, a negative number can be obtained, which leads to the other cause of undefined behavior and probably the "Runtime error" mentioned in the question:

```
if (array[product])   // <- 'product' can be negative
                      //  'array.at(product)' would have caught this error
{
    array[product] = false;
//…
```

An easy way to prevent this issue is using a type big enough to safely perform the operation, like:

```
long long int product = static_cast<long long int>(i) * j;
```

An alternative is to rewrite the logic to get rid of the troublesome part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

// Counts the number of prime numbers less than or equal to 'n'
long int count_primes(long int n)
{
    if (n < 2)   
        return 0;

    // Initialize the sieve. The first two elements (0 and 1) are ignored.
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n + 1, true);

    long int count = 0;
    for (long int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        // If a prime is found, delete all its multiples.
        if ( sieve[i] )
        {
            // Update the counter, once only.
            ++count;
            // Instead of performing a possible overflowing operation, you can
            // use a bigger type, capable of store the result, or a different logic:
            for (long int j = i + i; j <= n; j += i)
            {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function
    assert(count_primes(1) == 0);
    assert(count_primes(2) == 1);
    assert(count_primes(10) == 4);
    assert(count_primes(101) == 26);
    assert(count_primes(1000) == 168);
    assert(count_primes(10000) == 1229);
    assert(count_primes(100000) == 9592);
    assert(count_primes(1000000) == 78498);

    std::cout << "So far, so good.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Bob__ for the detailed explanation